# ToolStripContainer in VSPackage

Tags: c#, visual-studio, state, toolbar, vspackage

I have a VSPackage that has a couple of tool windows in it. As you will know tool windows derive from a class called WindowPane which is completely different from the standard Form class.

In my tool windows I have a ToolStrip hosted within a ToolStripContainer. What I would like to do is retain the positional information for the ToolStrip relative to its parent ToolStripContainer. I have looked at ToolStripManager.SaveSettings and ToolStripManager.LoadSettings but these require a Form as a parameter.

Has anyone else tried to do this?

Thanks,
Alan